# How to get a specific part of a string and use it for a calculation

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have to make a vending machine where I have a listbox (lstBeverage) to put all the drinks in.
The thing is that it must be in a string format (for example : cola of 33cl - 1,20 euro, fanta - 2,00 euro is what is in the listbox).

There is also a button btnAdd that whenever I click on it, it has to come into a label lblBeverage where it shows the string format from the listbox (for example cola of 33cl - 1,20 euro).
But there is also another label lblToPay that must only show the price of each drink. So only the 1,20 euro - part of the sentence. **Is there any way how I can do that?**

Final thing is that I need the amount from lblToPay and reduce it with buttons that indicates coins (btn2euro, btn1euro,..). To pay the amount of the drink.. I'm kinda stuck on how to do this as well.

Sorry if this ever sound complex. I'm a beginner programmer and stuck in this part of my exercise. If more details are required I can show exacly what I mean.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoStartup();
    }

    
    void DoStartup()
    {
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Cola 33cl - ${cola33.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Cola light 33cl - €{colaLight33.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Cola 50cl - €{cola50.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Cola light 50cl - €{colaLight50.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Icetea - €{iceTea.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Icetea light 33cl - €{iceTeaLight.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Spa rood 50cl - €{spaRood.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Spa blauw 50cl - €{spaBlauw.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Fristi 50cl - €{fristi.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Riva cola - €{riva.ToString("#,##0.00")}");
        lstBeverage.Items.Add($"Red Bull Super 50cl - €{redBull.ToString("#,##0.00")}");

        grpStep2.IsEnabled = false;
        grpStep3A.IsEnabled = false;
        grpStep3B.IsEnabled = false;


    }

    decimal cola33 = 1.2M;
    decimal colaLight33 = 1.2M;
    decimal cola50 = 2.0M;
    decimal colaLight50 = 2.0M;
    decimal iceTea = 1.2M;
    decimal iceTeaLight = 1.2M;
    decimal spaRood = 1.2M;
    decimal spaBlauw = 1.0M;
    decimal fristi = 1.6M;
    decimal riva = 0.9M;
    decimal redBull = 2.3M;

    string substr;

    private void btnConfirmBeverage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (lstBeverage.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            lblChosenBeverage.Content = lstBeverage.SelectedItem;
            string value = lblChosenBeverage.Content.ToString();
            string substr = "€" + value[^4..];
            lblToPay.Content = substr;


            if (lblChosenBeverage.Content.ToString() == "")
            {
                lstBeverage.IsEnabled = true;
                btnConfirmBeverage.IsEnabled = true;
                grpStep2.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lstBeverage.IsEnabled = false;
                btnConfirmBeverage.IsEnabled = false;
                grpStep2.IsEnabled = true;
            }

        }
        
        

    }
```

Comment: Don't describe the relevant code, show it.

Comment: The thing is: you don't write code based on the string that's selected from `lstBeverage`. Instead, you maintain a list of beverage objects that you manage in a list and you keep that list and the entries of `lstBeverage` in sync.

Comment: Hey Thomas, Is there a way that I can show you the program? It's kinda hard for me to explain it with words..

Comment: your title says *"How to get a specific part of a string and use it for a calculation"* but in your question - no string, no part, and no calculation. Seems that your question is about how to build a vending machine. I imagine a vending machine as `Service Locator` with a `Queue` at each `service point`. And every time service finds something `ICalculable` in  any queue, you just display its price, and release item [dequeue] after the payment

Comment: @Thomas Ok thank you. I also have to say that I don't have to use classes in this exercice it's all in the code behind with wpf

Comment: @Brian: sometimes classes are just the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

### String-based solution

To get the price from the string, you could use regular expressions:

```
    var foo = $"Cola 33cl - {(1.23654M).ToString("#,##0.00")}";
        
    var price = Regex.Match(foo, @"(\d+[,.]\d+)").Value;
        
    Console.WriteLine(price); // prints 1.24
```

For this to work, you need `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of your file.

Keep in mind that this solution returns only the **first occurence** of a number in a string. If there are multiple prices in your string, only the first is returned.

**WARNING: This is not a good practice and i strongly reccomend to use the class-bases solution below.**

### Class-Bases Solution

I would recommend to create a small class that holds the needed data for a beverage.

Something like this:

```
public class Beverage {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentSize { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your `lstBeverage` to hold objects of type `Beverage` instead of type `string` and initialize it like so:

```
lstBeverage.Items.Add(new Beverage
{
    Name = "Cola",
    ContentSize = "33cl",
    Price = 1.2M
});

...
```

Now, instead of using substring, you can use `(lstBeverage.SelectedItem as Beverage).Price` to get the price.

Comment: does it works without a cast? I suppose (cannot test right now) that you need somethng as `((Beverage)lstBeverage.SelectedItem).Price`; if not, you'll get a compiler error.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I've added it to my answer

Comment: @mamen thank you for your answer. For this specific exercice we are not supposed to use classes.. Since we're still learning about classes. Is there any way how to solve this without using classes? Also, I have to use a prebuild Xaml where i have to code on. I can show how the xaml look like

Comment: @Brian I have updated my answer to include a string-based solution.

Comment: @mamen thanks for the update. But where do I have to use this statement in my code? I have created a gif where you can see how my program looks like : https://imgur.com/2DGdp9i.
I have to fill the list in 'stap 1' with all the drinks and when clicked on 'bevestig' you will go to 'step 2' . The amount of the price have to show in the label 'nog te betalen' which i have to get out of a string text. Whenever I click on the coins below it has to decrease that amount

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you write a class which deals with your beverages. Since this class is just for formatting string and stuff, this class does not belong to the business model of your application, but rather the viewmodel (if you have such a distinction).

```
public class Beverage
{
    public decimal Price;
    public string Name;

    public Beverage(string name, decimal price)
    {
        Price = price;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string FullDisplay => $"{Name} - {DisplayPrice}";

    public string DisplayPrice => $"€{Price:#,##0.00}";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ToString() was called";
    }
}
```

Your window might use data binding to itself using

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

and the Listbox set up like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="lstBeverage" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Beverages}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="FullDisplay"
             SelectionChanged="LstBeverage_OnSelectionChanged"
             SelectionMode="Single">
    </ListBox>
    <Label x:Name="lblPrice" Content="Price will appear here">
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

The code behind file has the `Beverages` property for the item source of the ListBox as well as a bit of code handling the selected item:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ICollection<Beverage> Beverages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Beverage>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Beverages.Add(new Beverage("Cola 33cl", 1.2M));
        Beverages.Add(new Beverage("Cola light 33cl", 1.2M));
        Beverages.Add(new Beverage("Cola 50cl ", 2.0M));
    }

    private void LstBeverage_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstBeverage.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        Beverage selected = (Beverage) lstBeverage.SelectedItems[0];
        lblPrice.Content = selected.DisplayPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm absolutely not a WPF guy yet. If this is crap, please let me know what's wrong. I'm glad I can learn something.

Comment: Thank you! Will watch it tomorrow but I must say that I'm a beginner in classes and this exercise that I have to make is normally to code without using classes. If you have another solution on this without using classes that would be very helpfull, Thomas

Comment: @Brian: I understand your request. You know, I am a trainer for students. And for this task classes and objects are the way to go. Doing it without classes is certainly possible, but it's soooo wrong, really! It's like receiving an email, then printing it and then scanning it just to read it on your screen. Maybe I can write an answer for your exact string problem this evening, but I'll mark it with a big fat warning. If you ever do this in a real software development project, other developers might get angry with you.

Comment: Thank you for the positive feedback. I understand it completely but our teachers want us to make complicated projects without using classes which makes no sence but this is now the case.. Again if you want more details for the projects I can give it to you as well. Note that it's just a screenshot of my program..